# Disallow apt to install local deb packages

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt

I have to administer a bunch ubuntu clients, where the users are required not to get full sudo rights.

The requirements of each user are rather specific, so I have to install packages for each of them a dozen times a day remotely. Obviously this is not ideal. I would like give them sudo apt install rights (I know how to restrict their sudo capabilities to that single command already), but I don't want to allow the installation of manually downloaded .deb packages.

Packages shall only be installed through the configured repositories.

I read something about the /etc/apt/preferences.d/ files, and tried the following already

```
# in a file called /etc/apt/preferences.d/block-local
Package: *
Pin: origin ""
Pin-Priority: -1
```

But this does not prevent anything. Is there a way to achieve my goal using apt/preferences or any other configuration? Thanks!

Comment: You can prevent running some commands under the `sudo`. Use the exclamation mark in the `sudoers` file.

Comment: But I cannot prevent a user from installing a deb package this way. Something like ! ... /usr/bin/apt install *.deb is not going to work, since the latter is only an argument to the actual command that can be controlled using sudoers. Also, I'm not even sure wildcards work within sudoers file?

Comment: Yep, `sudoers` file syntax supports wildcards. Better search some human-friendly how-to instead `man sudoers`.